# Running Jupyter notebook from ubuntu server I'm ssh'ed into

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu-14.04, pyspark, jupyter, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to set up Spark on an ubuntu server. My preferred way to use spark is through a Jupyter notebook (pyspark).

When I run

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

It starts it within the terminal. Ideally I'd like it to feed me a host address where I can access the Jupyter notebook from another computer (on the same network). Any ideas?

[image: See image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start the notebook server with

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*' --no-browser
```

which would allow access to the notebook server by visiting `http://10.0.0.10:8888` in your browser, assuming that `10.0.0.10` is the IP address of the machine running the server.

The `--no-browser` option will prevent the text browser from opening. Instead you should see the exact address you need to visit printed to the console.

Be careful with that though, because this will allow access from all machines on your local network. So people on the same network may run arbitrary Python code on your host.